# Not able to Align Material Toggle Button in Android

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I am trying to get single user input from 4 options (e.g. tool 1, tool 2, tool 3,tool 4).
Earlier I used radio-group later I came across a great UI design. So I tried to element that using Material Toggle Button.
https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button

So I thought I will place them as :

> ```
>              Tool 1        Tool 2
>              Tool 3        Tool 4
> ```

But as I mentioned I have 4 buttons, they are getting placed on a single line (Horizontally) and not showing full text.
e.g.:

> Tool 1     Tool 2 Tool 3 To...

I tried to add layouts like constraint layout/ table layout, but they are not working, I think that is not supported.
e.g:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Constraint-layout
        ....>
             <Button ...../>
             <Button ...../>
             <Button ...../>
             <Button ...../>
      </Constraint-layout>
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Comment: please share your full xml code

Comment: @RajendraMahato you can visit the link... My code is same to same... Please try to understand the problem... The problem is not with the code...

Comment: MaterialButtonToggleGroup is like LinearLayout. You can either choose orientation: horizontal or orientation: vertical. I am not sure that you can make that with only one toggle group. You can do that with a workaround solution to use LinearLayout as root with horizontal orientation, then put two toggle groups with vertical orientation. Then just handle clicks in your code because now you'll have to handle clicks of one toggle group when the other one is pressed.

Comment: you can try @SlothCoding answer. I was thinking the same thing

Comment: @SlothCoding Indeed...Using 2 Material Toggle Button is a sightly lengthy  way... But I was thinking "why we can align then directly, or set their locations as we do with other ui components"

Comment: @techfangirl I answered below. It says in the documentation that MaterialButtonToggleGroup is just LinearLayout in the background. And like in LinearLayout you can choose either vertical or horizontal orientation. If you want to align 2 views side by side and others below in the same layout you need to use a bunch of linear layouts to achieve this. That's why we use other layouts for this. But with ToggleGroup you can't, so you need to use a workaround solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MaterialButtonToggleGroup documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) it says this:

> A common container for a set of related, toggleable MaterialButtons. The MaterialButtons in this group will be shown on a single line.

And also this:

> MaterialButtonToggleGroup is a LinearLayout. Using android:layout_width="MATCH_PARENT" and removing android:insetBottom android:insetTop on the children is recommended if using VERTICAL.

This being said there is no way for you to use any `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` attribute to change the orientation as you wanted. There is a workaround for this but I am not sure about how much it is okay to do this.

You can do this in your XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">    

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you get this:

[image: Tablelike buttons]

The next issue you need to resolve is to handle click events on each toggle group. Because when you click on one group the other one needs to respond too. This needs to be done with listeners. There is documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup#addonbuttoncheckedlistener

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with `MaterialToggleGroup` and `MaterialButton`, for multiple columns and rows with unregular arrangment I suggest that you use `TableLayout`, and use   selector `Drawable` to reflect which item is selected,